# How to extract the values from one cell over a list?

Tags: r, list

I have two data frames within one list.

How do I print the values from specifically the cell of row 1, column 2 from both those data frames contained within the list? So I will end up with two values as there are two data frames within my list.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and then extract the elements with row/column index

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) x[1,2])
```

which is returned in a `list`.  If we need a `vector`, either `unlist` the `lapply` output or use `sapply`

```
sapply(lst1, function(x) x[1,2])
```

Or using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
lapply(lst1, function(x) ss(x, 1, 2))
```